# I want to keep the same hierarchy when import a character. But it keeps on adding an "armature" on top of it

Tags: rigging, export

I have an issue where the character has this hierarchy in unity [image]. But as soon as i add it in blender and make some changes, the hierarchy changes to
[image]. Is there a way where i can keep the hierarchy same. ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How are you importing the character?  If, for example, you are importing by appending from another Blend file and the character has an armature in that Blend file, you'll just have to delete it.  If you are importing an mhx2 file, there's an option in the importer to not import the armature.  Other importers have other approaches.

Answer (score 0):

By default, using the shortcut Ctrl P to bind the mesh to an armature, two actions are performed (at least): adding an armature modifier and parenting the mesh to the armature. The lattest is useful only if the armature is transformed in object mode, and I think that Unity also doesn't need it.

So probably you can simply select all mesh objects and press Alt P to remove the parenting: actions performed in pose mode will be preserved (and Unity should do the same), while the hierarchy will stay untouched.

Answer (score 0):

Some of Blender's exporters have an option to handle the Armature node.

Example with FBX: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_fbx.html#armatures

[image]